# How do I return to the first record using BindingSource.MoveNext();

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm kinda new in C# programming and I'm having the following issue:
I'm using `BindingSource.MoveNext();` in order to navigate through records but when I reach the last record I would like to return to the first one if there's no record to move next. Can I get any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// If you are not at the end of the list, move to the next item 
// in the BindingSource. 
if (BindingSource1.Position + 1 < BindingSource1.Count)
    BindingSource1.MoveNext();
else // Otherwise, move back to the first item. 
    BindingSource1.MoveFirst();
```